# set two columns with same where conditions

Tags: python, pandas, where-clause

I need to reject records based on a set of conditions. On top of storing if the row has been rejected, I want to keep track also of the criteria which kicked the records off. This is what I am currently doing:

```
np.random.seed(seed=1)
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('abcd'))

#condition 1
df["accepted"]=np.where(df.a<10, "No", "")
df["reason"]=np.where(df.a<10, "a less than 10 ", "")

#condition 2
df["accepted"]=np.where(df.b<30, "No", df.accepted)
df["reason"]=np.where(df.b<30, df.reason+"b less than 10 ", df.reason)
```

the set of conditions is large and they are kind of complex in the real scenario. The conditions are going to change over time, and I want to reduce the maintenance, so I tried to incorporate the two where statements into one:

```
df[["accepted","reason"]]=np.where(df.c>20, ["No",df.reason + "c higher than 20 "], [df.accepted,df.reason])
```

but I got:

> **ValueError**: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,) (2,) (2,100)

Is there a way to set two columns in the same where statement? Or do you have an alternative approach to suggest? My goal is to maintain the sequential approach (i.e. rejecting the rows condition by condition), and to have a way to assess which condition rejected record. My dataframe has about 100k records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion: use np.select. Create your list of conditions, in the right order, then create your list of expected outputs, again in the right order and pass it into np.select. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html

Hope the code below helps :

```
np.random.seed(seed=1)
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('abcd'))

cond1 = df['a']<10
cond2 = df['b']<30
cond3 = (df['a']<10) & (df['b']<30)
cond4 = ~((df['a']<10) | (df['b']<30))
condlist=[cond3,cond2,cond1,cond4]
choicelist = ['both','no','no','']
reasonlist = [ 'a less than 10, b less than 10','a less than 10','b less than 
                                                                  10','']

df['accept']=np.select(condlist,choicelist)
df['reason'] = np.select(condlist,reasonlist)

df.head(

    a   b   c   d   accept  reason
0   37  12  72  9   no      a less than 10
1   75  5   79  64  no      a less than 10
2   16  1   76  71  no      a less than 10
3   6   25  50  20  both    a less than 10, b less than 10
4   18  84  11  28
```

With this, you can add more conditions, or change the conditions over time.

Note that I put the 'a less than 10, b less than 10' condition first before the others. The whole aim is to ensure that the correct order is set when listing out the conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and apologize for the delay in coming back to you. Having the condition stored inside a variable indeed reduces maintenance. However, I cannot concatenate the output of multiple subsequent rejections, e.g.: 
    df['reason']=np.select([cond2],df.reason+["b less than 30"])     please note that the number of conditions can grow significantly and I cannot evaluate all the possible combinations of the conditions and related output. I can create a new column every time and then concatenate the two - so probably this is going to be my correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply` method. See the implementation below:

```
def update(row):
    if row.c > 20:
        row.accepted = "No"
        row.reason = row.reason + 'c higher than 20 '
    return row

df = df.apply(lambda row: update(row), axis=1)
```

You can write all your conditions in `update()` method.

Comment: this is a nice solution, thanks. it is working fine but it is a bit slower than the np.where conditions. the number of condition is going to grow a lot in the future and I would like to start a structure that is sustainable. I will wait a day to see if something more time efficient come out, then I will mark your answer as correct. Again thanks for your time.